# Multiple images in image flipper Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, viewflipper

I'm using this code to dynamically pop images on the slider using Image Flipper.

```
flipper= (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);     
     for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
                {
                //  This will create dynamic image view and add them to ViewFlipper
                  Button image = new Button(getApplicationContext());

                    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stock_bg);
                    image.setText("Sps"+i);
                   // image.getLayoutParams().height=40;
                     // image.getLayoutParams().width=40;
                    flipper.addView(image);
                }
```

I have set sliding animation to it. The issue is that it fits one image on the whole screen width and then animates to other. While I want the image size to remain same and it should not fit it to the entire screen. Also note that if I change the flipper width from wrap content to custom width, it will not slide the entire screen. Putting it simple, how can I force the flipper to show more then 1 image on the screen at a time.

Comment: You can use viewpager instead of this.

Comment: Can you direct me to any tutorial or relevant link plz?

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader